# XSL Specific Attribute conforming

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a bunch of docbook files that have have varying attributes on on their imagedata.  I want to have them all have 1 unique attribute, and 3 identical attributes:

```
  <section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5" xml:id="cancelDia">
    <title>Screenshot</title>
    <mediaobject>
      <imageobject>
        <imagedata fileref="screenshots/cancelDialog.png" scalefit="1" width="100%" contentdepth="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
    </mediaobject>
  </section>
```

The fileref is unique and should be left alone, but scalefit, width, and contentdepth need to be the same among all `<imagedata>`.  One problem is that most image data have scalefit, a few have width, and the rare one has contentdepth.  How do I ensure, even if they already have that attribute, all my `<imagedata>` have identical scalefit, width, and contentdepth?

Note: I'm not sure if this matters, but I'm using docbook 5

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an almost identical solution to that of @Alejandro, that just adjusts the default-namespace issue and uses parameterized approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:doc="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
 xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
 exclude-result-prefixes="doc">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="doc:imagedata">
        <imagedata fileref="{@fileref}"
                       scalefit="1" width="100%" contentdepth="100%"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<section version="5" xml:id="cancelDia" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
    <title>Screenshot</title>
    <mediaobject>
        <imageobject>
            <imagedata fileref="screenshots/cancelDialog.png" 
                       scalefit="1" width="100%" contentdepth="100%" />
        </imageobject>
    </mediaobject>
</section>
```

**Edit**: Matching new input sample.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes this works for my original question, although I can't seem to get it to work for the docbook namespace.  I've updated my question so it's closer to what I'm looking at.

Comment: You may need to declare the docbook namespace `xmlns:docbook="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` in the XSLT and adjust the `@match="docbook:imagedata"`

Comment: I've tried that, and unfortunatly it also throws: xmlns="" xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" into the <imagedata> for some reason

Comment: Good answer, +1. I provided my own, which just adjusts for the default namespace and uses parameters for the values.

Comment: @Ace: That's because you need the namespace URI for two task: matching input `imagedata` and output an `imagedata` element. But because you need a prefix - URI binding for the matching XPath pattern, you have to strip this in scope namespace for literal result elements.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
 xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="d ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pAttribs">
  <p scalefit="1" width="100%" contentdepth="100%"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="d:imagedata">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@fileref
    |
     ext:node-set($pAttribs)/*/@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
         version="5" xml:id="cancelDia">
    <title>Screenshot</title>
    <mediaobject>
        <imageobject>
            <imagedata fileref="screenshots/cancelDialog.png"
             scalefit="1"
             width="100%"
             contentdepth="100%"/>
        </imageobject>
    </mediaobject>
</section>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
         version="5" xml:id="cancelDia">
   <title>Screenshot</title>
   <mediaobject>
      <imageobject>
         <imagedata fileref="screenshots/cancelDialog.png" 
                    scalefit="1" width="100%" contentdepth="100%"/>
      </imageobject>
   </mediaobject>
</section>
```

**Do note**:

All the desired values are set as attributes of an element inside of an external `<xsl:param>`

Comment: Why does the imagedata tag change and also adds xmlns there?  Is there a way to prevent that? *EDIT* seems you just need to make docbook the deault namespace?  Good Answer as well though.

Comment: @Ace: Good observation. See not only this fix but a new, better parameterisation technique. :)